# Drawing non-gradient circle with colorstop

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I draw a non-gradient circle with colorstop, something like this:

[image]

The closest I got was using radial gradient http://jsfiddle.net/8tdz0bo4/2/:

[image]

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 100,
    y = 75,
    innerRadius = 1,
    outerRadius = 50,
    radius = 60;

var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, innerRadius, x, y, outerRadius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'transparent');
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is quite simple : to avoid any gradient, just build several steps having same start and end color like in :

```
 0.0 red   // first red step 
 0.5 red   // end of first red step
 0.5 blue  // second blue step
 1.0 blue. // end of blue step
```

With this idea, your code becomes :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 100,
  y = 75,
  innerRadius = 1,
  outerRadius = 50,
  radius = 60;

var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, innerRadius, x, y, outerRadius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'transparent');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'transparent');
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these

```
gradient.addColorStop(0.2, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(0.2, 'transparent');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8tdz0bo4/3/